# What does this sentence on BBC means: ""All baa myself: Is this Britain's loneliest sheep?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

**All baa myself: Is this Britain's loneliest sheep?** [BBC - Britain's loneliest sheep](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-highlands-islands-67237956)

What does "All baa myself" mean? I couldn't quite understand it.

Comment: Source of the joke: https://youtu.be/iN9CjAfo5n0?t=55

Comment: British journalists infamously love a *pun*

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this story was only considered publishable because of the beautiful headline.

Comment: Association: there is a well-known pop song with the refrain "All by  myself". Originally sung by Eric Carmen and Celine Dion as well known for it. The melody is based on the Rachmaninoffs 2nd piano concerto (section for un-necessayr knowledge)

Comment: That sheep needs to shear up a bit!

Comment: Update:  Sheep now rescued!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is word play. The word "by" has been replaced by "baa".  The sound that sheep make is represented in English as "baa"  (Sheep say "baa", cows say "moo", cats say "miaow").  "All by myself" means "alone".

Comment: (I thought that cats say *meow*.)

Comment: @apaderno It depends on the cat's accent.

Comment: I think it's a [pun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pun#Noun), but a *play on words* (wordplay) also work.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Aren't those the same thing?

Comment: @gidds  Both work, but I prefer *pun* because they are supposed to be funny, and they are obviously jokes; wordplay is more on the whimsical, and the "Oh, that clever!" thing. Personal opinion, of course!

Comment: I think you're missing out on mentioning that "***All By Myself***" is a famous song lyric; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iN9CjAfo5n0&t=55s

Comment: @apaderno - they could say _miau_ in around 1900, according to an old children's book I once saw.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Would *miau* and *meow* have the same pronunciation, nowadays? (Funny fuct, in Italian cats say *miao*; kitties could say *miau* because they are younger and their pronunciation is not yet perfect.)

Comment: @apaderno - in English, _miau_ and _meow_ sound the same. That sound which a cat makes is called a _mew_ which does not!

Comment: A cat actually says *nyaa*

Comment: Hm, in NA English I've only seen it spelled "meow". I know in French it's "miaou". Perhaps the continental influence has altered the spelling in the UK? Although "miau" would certainly have to be pronounced the same as "meow" usually is, it's such a foreign-looking spelling that I think it would startle many speakers over here.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - I am fairly sure that _meow_ is the majority spelling in the UK. I don't know how my cat would spell it. _Miau_ is an odd outlier I once saw in a kid's story book published around 1900.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meow%2Cmiaow&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiaow%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meow%2Cmiaow%2Cmiau%2Cmiaou&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true